# What's the name of this wavy curve?

Tags: geometry, terminology, plane-curves

What's the name of the curve you get from changing the x or y frequency on what was previously a path around an ellipse?

The equation would be:

f(t) = (A*cos(u*t), B*sin(v*t))

And it looks like a wavy line instead of an ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you perhaps mean [Lissajous curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve)?

Answer (score 0):

Previously means when $ u = v$ ?

Lissajou figures. If $ u/v = 2 , 3 $ , ie multiple arguments, Lissajous close after $ u v $ LCM waves ..